# Excel group transposed columns by date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table, power-query

I'm having trouble transposing data to get the format that I'd like. I have pay period end dates in one column and employee names in the other column, and I'd like format it so that each column header is a pay period date and the rows are the employees on the payroll for that period.

Here's the data as it is formatted now:

```
pay period   name
3/6/2015     John Smith
3/6/2015     Jane Smith
4/5/2015     John Smith
4/5/2015     Jane Smith
4/5/2015     Joe Smith
4/19/2015    John Smith
4/19/2015    Jane Smith
4/19/2015    Joe Smith
5/3/2015     John Smith
5/3/2015     Jane Smith
5/3/2015     Joe Smith
5/3/2015     Julie Smith
```

And here is how I would like it to be formatted:

```
3/6/2015    4/5/2015    4/19/2015   5/3/2015
John Smith  John Smith  John Smith  John Smith
Jane Smith  Joe Smith   Joe Smith   Joe Smith
            Jane Smith  Jane Smith  Jane Smith
                                    Julie Smith
```

I've tried using Get & Transform/Power Query to transpose the data using Pivot Columns, using the names in the pay period column to create new columns, with "name" as the values column, and aggregation turned off. Instead of getting the format I want, I get the pay period dates as column headers and then a single cell reading "error" in row 2. I have checked the column types to verify that "pay period" has date as its type and "name" has text as its type.

I'm not sure if I'm simply doing the query wring or if I should go about this in another way. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I too wish for more options with pivot tables.  Here is a vba sub to do this transposition for you.  This is just the basics and could be more robust.  This does not sort your dates or your names and takes them as is.  It adds a sheet and takes data from the current active sheet.

```
Sub Transpose()

Dim dateDict As Object
Dim numRows As Long
Dim rowPos As Long
Dim dateVal As String

Dim currSheet As Worksheet
Set currSheet = ActiveSheet

Set dateDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
numRows = currSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
rowPos = 2
Do While rowPos <= numRows
  dateVal = currSheet.Cells(rowPos, 1).Value2
  If dateDict.exists(dateVal) Then
  Else
    dateDict.Add dateVal, 0
  End If
  rowPos = rowPos + 1
Loop

Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

Dim i As Long
Dim newPos As Long
Dim Column As Long
Column = 0
For Each myKey In dateDict
  newPos = 2
  rowPos = 2
  Column = Column + 1
  mySheet.Cells(1, Column).Value2 = myKey
  Do While rowPos <= numRows
    If currSheet.Cells(rowPos, 1).Value2 = myKey Then
      mySheet.Cells(newPos, Column).Value2 = currSheet.Cells(rowPos, 2).Value2
      newPos = newPos + 1
    End If
    rowPos = rowPos + 1
  Loop
Next

End Sub
```